# TestMethod's [DataSource] loading before [AssemblyInitialize], need it to be the other way around

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I have a bunch of tests in an assembly. These tests all live in `[TestClass]` classes and are marked with a `[DataSource]` pointing to Sql Server. Each of these test classes extends a BaseTest also marked with `[TestClass]`. I have an `[AssemblyInitialize]` method in BaseTest that creates the view on the server for DataSource to use (I'd kill to be able to use a tvf instead). This works fine when the tests run through MTM. As of a few weeks ago it stopped working locally - Init isn't being called until AFTER DataSource loads (manually created `my_view`, traced the server, put a breakpoint on `Init()` and didn't hit the breakpoint until after I saw the test do a `SELECT * FROM [my_view]`).

Overview of code:

```
[TestClass]
MyTests : BaseTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("..SqlClient",CONN,"my_view",..Sequential)]
    public void MyTest(){}
}

[TestClass]
BaseTest
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext testContext){//create my_view}

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void Cleanup(){//drop view}

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit(){}

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup(){}

}
```

Things I've tried to no avail:

1. Adding a [TestMethod] to the BaseTest
2. Putting [AssemblyInitialize] in MyTests
3. Ensuring there is only one [AssemblyInitialize]
4. Running in VS 2013 instead of 2015
5. Running with Keep Test Execution Engine running on and off

Comment: "As of a few weeks ago it stopped working locally" - what changed a few weeks ago?